# PHP Regex to insert specific strings in a string in order to print a code128 barcode

Tags: php, zpl-ii, code128

in order to print a code128 barcode with a zebra printer in ZPL II language, i'm trying to convert a string (which is my barcode) into a new string. This new string  is the same string with some specific commands related to switching between ALPHA and NUMERIC modes. Switching to NUMERIC mode helps making your barcode more compact.
so lets say the barcode i want to print is : `C00J025042101110823611001150119611`
the result should be this :

```
>:C00J>5025042101110823611001150119611

>: mean we Start in ALPHA
>5 Mean we switch from ALPHA to NUMERIC ONLY
>6 Mean we switch from NUMERIC to ALPHA
```

So what i'm looking for is (if possible) a REGEX which will insert `>5` or `>6` in my string.

here is another example:

barcode to print = `CJYJY10442101110S23611001150119611`

String to send to printer = `>:CJYJY1>50442101110>6S2>53611001150119611`

Some more example, in order to understand how it starts. On the left the barcode to print, on the right the code sent to the printer.

`C000025042101110823611001150119611` `>:C0>500025042101110823611001150119611`
`CJ00025042101110823611001150119611` `>:CJ>500025042101110823611001150119611`
`C0J0025042101110823611001150119611` `>:C0J0>5025042101110823611001150119611`
`C00J025042101110823611001150119611` `>:C00J>5025042101110823611001150119611`
`C000J25042101110823611001150119611` `>:C000J2>55042101110823611001150119611`
`C0000J5042101110823611001150119611` `>:C>50000>6J>55042101110823611001150119611`
`C00000J042101110823611001150119611` `>:C0>50000>6J0>542101110823611001150119611`

Extra note from the ZEBRA ZPL II documentation:

> Code 128 subsets A and C are programmed as pairs of digits, 00-99, in the field data string. [...] in subset C, they are printed as entered.
>   NOTE: Non-integers programmed as the first character of a digit pair (D2) are ignored. However, non-integers programmed as the second character of a digit pair (2D) invalidate the entire digit pair, and the pair is ignored. An extra, unpaired digit in the field data string just before a code shift is also ignored.

Subset C is NUMERIC, invoked by ">6"

Comment: From what i know there is no criteria, it's up to you to choose when you want to switch to ALPHA or NUMERIC. ZPL-II langage is not simple i wanted to be clear enough. it is possible to stay in ALPHA from the begining and up to the end of the string, but it makes the barcode very large. switching to NUMERIC mode is a trick to reduce the barcode size a lot.

Comment: you are right, this was the string generated by my label designer software (Codesoft), i don't know why it didn't do it that way...but anyway it should work. btw here is a picture with the barcodein Alpha only and below the same barcode switching from alpha to NUM, you can see the width difference : https://i.imgur.com/SvDpZ2D.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use preg_replace with array arguments:

```php
$result = preg_replace(
    array(
        '/(^\D)/',
        '/(\D)(\d)/',
        '/(\d)(\D)/',
    ),
    array(
        '>:$1',
        '$1>5$2',
        '$1>6$2',
    ),
    $code
);
```

**UPD**

According to the last comments you can try to switch between modes only if pair numbers found.

```php
$result = preg_replace(
    array(
        '/(^\D)/',
        '/((?:\d{2})+)/',
        '/\>[56]$/',
    ),
    array(
        '>:$1',
        '>5$1>6',
        '',
    ),
    $code
);
```

Comment: this gives me an error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: Which version of PHP do you running?

Comment: i'm running PHP 5.3.13 on my server...for some reason i can't upgrade it for the moment.

Comment: Have just updated code snipped according to PHP version < 5.4. In PHP 5.4 you can repace `array()` with `[]`

Comment: Well, when i send to the printer the resulted code (which is 100% correct) the last number on the right is missing when i read the barcode with my scanner... i don't know if it's because we do this `>:C>500J>50250....` instead of this `>:C00J>50250....`

Comment: Сan you please provide me with alpha mode restrictions if any.

Comment: omg that's not very simple, the documentation about this is here : https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/code_128.htm#Sample%20ZPL%20switching%20from%20Subset%20C%20to%20B%20to%20A the switch between ALPHA/NUM can be seen in that picture : https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/images/128_001.gif i'm wondering if it's something about "pairs"...the strings have to be pairs and not odd when converting ? i have no clue about how it is working...

Comment: Well, so using my label software i generated some barcodes and captured the results. step by step i moved to the right the first Letter to see what is the rule..i edited my question and added the examples.

Comment: Well, so this is what is actually happening to me, it is explained in a note in my link above : "Code 128 subsets A and C are programmed as pairs of digits, 00-99, in the field data string. [...] in subset C, they are printed as entered.
NOTE: Non-integers programmed as the first character of a digit pair (D2) are ignored. However, non-integers programmed as the second character of a digit pair (2D) invalidate the entire digit pair, and the pair is ignored. An extra, unpaired digit in the field data string just before a code shift is also ignored."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194866/discussion-between-cetipabo-and-vitaliy-krushelnitsky).

Comment: Vitaliy, your update is 100% working. you are genius, thank you very very much for your help. you just missed a single quote in the first array.